# PowerQuery - All Combinations - Cross Product - Cartesian Product

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a table in Powerquery (simplified version of my actual table) where I have a product a bomline and a BOMproduct.

| Product | Bomline | Bomproduct |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1.1 |
| A | 2 | 1.2 |
| A | 3 | 1.3 |

My desired end result of the table would be the following table, do you have any Idea how to accoplish that in PowerQuery? I'm thinking of storing a list of all combinations, but don't know where to start.

| Product | Bomline | Bomproduct | All_combinations |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1.1 | 1.1 |
| A | 2 | 1.2 | 1.2 |
| A | 3 | 1.3 | 1.3 |
| A | 1 | 1.1 | 1.3 |
| A | 2 | 1.2 | 1.1 |
| A | 3 | 1.3 | 1.2 |
| A | 1 | 1.1 | 1.2 |
| A | 2 | 1.2 | 1.3 |
| A | 3 | 1.3 | 1.1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple Cartesian product. If your table looks like this:

[image]

Add a custom column and write the name of your previous step (mine is called Changed Type).

[image]

[image]

Then expand the relevant column:

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Product", type text}, {"Bomline", Int64.Type}, {"Bomproduct", type number}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each #"Changed Type"),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Bomproduct"}, {"Bomproduct.1"})
in
    #"Expanded Custom"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, simple but very useful solution, thanks!